# Joining Data From Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I never did such PHP/MYSQL tricks to join multitables. Please who has experience in this field Help:

```
$qry=mysql_query("select {$table_prefix}user_cv.*, {$table_prefix}advertising.* from {$table_prefix}user_cv, {$table_prefix}advertising where {$table_prefix}user_cv.publish='yes' and {$table_prefix}advertising.publish='Y'");
```

mysql query return 0 results .

Comment: What is in your variables at the time you try to run it? If you look at the actual query, should it even return data? By that I mean is 0 a valid number of rows or is it throwing a SQL error - or is the query valid just not returning the data you expected?

Comment: yes its given no error when i try 

`select  ow_advertising.* from ow_advertising where  ow_advertising.publish='Y'`

mysql return 2 results

instead of `select ow_user_cv.*, ow_advertising.* from ow_user_cv, ow_advertising where ow_user_cv.publish='yes' and ow_advertising.publish='Y'`

Comment: Any relation between these two tables ?

Comment: no relation between these two tables

Comment: So why are you asking for a join query when there is no relation b/w 2 tables

Comment: i want to fetch records from two table in while loop. thats why

Comment: What are the data in your tables?

Comment: welcome to the world of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry = "SELECT {$table_prefix}user_cv.*, {$table_prefix}advertising.*
        FROM {$table_prefix}user_cv
        LEFT JOIN {$table_prefix}advertising ON {$table_prefix}advertising.publish='Y'
        WHERE {$table_prefix}user_cv.publish='yes'";
mysql_query($qry);
```

I did not test this! I could be wrong but it might be a step in the right direction. (Still new myself)

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).